# Windows 10 Mobile not connecting to Microsoft account

Tags: windows-10-mobile, sync, microsoft-account

Even did a reset, but still nothing changed.
This is what the issue is:-
[image]

[image]

My Lumia 640 is not connecting to the Microsoft Account, or downloading/updating apps from the Store when it is connected to the Wi-Fi. It works fine on Mobile Data connection. However, all my other devices, such as two PCs, some android phones are working completely fine. I have checked my date/time and even reset it. I have reset my phone twice, and even changed the language and region to that of US together. But still no help.
I have checked the settings of my router, and confirmed that there was no blocking feature enabled on it. But still, from yesterday, my phone is behaving strangely. Please help!

**Update 1**: All the above problem occurs only when the phone is connected to Wi-Fi. My phone works fine on Mobile Data. Please help.

Comment: Are Date/Time set correctly?

Comment: Yup, also, the phone connects to the account when using Mobile Data, not Wi-Fi. I forgot to mention this in the description. i just update it.

Comment: Sounds like something on the Wi-Fi is blocking access to the store - can you log-in/browse via a browser when connected to that Wi-Fi network?

Comment: Interesting, I just encountered almost the same issue with my brand new Lumia 950 that has just arrived. I can't add a MS Account either.

Comment: Actually, the problem is now solved. The main problem was from the ISP's end. They were having problem with their servers. Now everything's fine.

Comment: @ReeshabhRanjan Why don't add your comment as answer and mark it. Your question still remains as an unanswered one.

Comment: @KolappanNathan, wouldn't it be a lame answer. Probably its better in comments, no?

Comment: No. I wouldn't consider it lame. It is the actual solution that solved your problem. If anyone gets the same kind of problem in future they would know to call their ISP's customer care. Many don't read the comments you see. An marked answer would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this issue by reinstalling the OS through the [Windows Devices Recovery Tool](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/windows-device-recovery-tool-faq). This offered my a newer firmware version for my device, which might have fixed the problem.

You could try doing a simple hard reset first.

Comment: Hard reset can fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Okay guys, this is the guy who asked the question above!
The problem was from the ISP's end. There was a technical issue in my area due to which web services of Microsoft and Google got inaccessible. Hence, it reflected in my phone. 
If you stumbled upon this question anyways, you may try checking if the websites too not open on your PC or other devices. You may want to call the ISP then!